# Does docker compose automatically put the containers in the same network?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, containers

I was recently trying to containerize an application that uses three services. When starting their containers separately with docker run, I also need to put them in the same network otherwise they can't communicate. But I just wrote a docker-compose.yaml file to run them at the same time and they can communicate with each other even without specifying their network interface. Why is that?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Try running `docker network ls` and see if there is a network created for your application. Also `docker compose ps` from the same working dir as your compose file can tell you what services and ports are running. If you haven't exposed ports so that services can communicate via the host, then they are using docker network

Comment: As a corollary to this, for most typical Compose applications you don't need to mention `networks:` at all, nor `container_name:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose create a stack with a default network.

From docker-compose documentation :
"By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by the service's name."

If you want to customize, you need to use network directive in your docker-compose.yml file.

Hope this help